# Moving more than 200 SQL Server 2008 Databases to another machine

Tags: sql-server

I have a server which is running SQL Server 2008R2 SP1 and there are more than 200 online databases with their specific login and I want to move all of these databases to another machine with the same software  SQL Server 2008R2 SP1.
I can afford downtime up to 8 hours so I'm not looking for complex solution like database mirroring and logshipping.

I have tried Backup & Restore, it work fine but trouble me in two ways :
1-  I couldn't transfer login to new server so all of my users will have to create their user again which will my users to get angry.
(I have tried to script all of the logins from the security section but since I have realize the hash algorithm between two system maybe different, I cannot transfer my logins in this way)

2 - I have to backup & restore each database one by one which is so time consuming.

I have also tried copy wizard, but I have encountered with following error message at the final stage :
"SQL Server schedule job" job failed the job was invoked by user sa step to run was step 1.

Since mysource server is running based on windows server 2003, I cannot use the powershell V3 solution.

I have done many searches but all I found was a solution to transfer one database to another server.
But since I'm looking for a solution to transfer mass databases, this situation is being hair pulling and so difficult So I wil be very appreciated if you can provide me an easy and practical solution.

Comment: If you use windows authentication then this can all be scripted. If you use SQL Authentication.... that's just another reason you shouldn't be using it.

Comment: If you can't use PowerShell, you can still use `cmd` in combination with `sqlcmd`. Batch scripting isn't as powerful or convenient as PowerShell, but in this case it should get the job done. As for transferring SQL Server logins, check http://www.sqlmatters.com/Articles/Copying%20logins%20and%20passwords%20from%20one%20SQL%20Server%20to%20another.aspx, it seems helpful.

Answer (score 0):

for moving logins between servers

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/918992
[moving logins][1]

then backup and restore all databases in that migraton day using pre built restore script if the db size is small , later restore the differential backups and make it online. if the size is an issue then implement log shipping or mirroring